# Generate ER/Workflow diagram from PHP code/script logic

Tags: php, workflow, documentation-generation, lazy-evaluation, erd

Is there anything out there to read my source code and generate a ER or Workflow Diagram from the logic of my script?

Yes I've added the 'Lazy' tag for this question

Comment: Doxygen uses graphviz for generating diagrams, so I'd *assume* that you'd be able to configure it to output ER diagrams as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visit http://www.visual-paradigm.com/
 they has revers engineering and it is usefull